# Sharepoint Online External Content Types WCF Service

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, bcs, external-content-type, wcf

I have this issue I can't find solution for a couple of days now as I am working on creating External Content Types for Sharepoint Online 2013 (trial period will expire in the next 5 days :( ).

I strictly followed this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff953200(v=office.14).aspx

I know my wcf service works as I can view the wsdl and service in the browser

[image]

[image]

Now when I open the Sharepoint Designer 2013 or 2010 I could not successfully add connection using WCF Service as I always got this error [image]

I feel that Sharepoint Designer can see the WCF Service because the progress bar is connecting, however, it seems like there is problem reading the returned result.

[image]

Note that I'm connected to my Sharepoint online and have added secure store properly. However, since my WCF is hosted locally, I think I don't need the secure store at this stage. But because of the error, I also try to use my secure store with app id name "LOCALHOST" and supply my local username/password in this format domain\username.

[image]

I really appreciate if you could help me this pain in the neck issue.

[image]

**Update**

If I put my service in public such in Azure I've got different error though.But again, I can view the wcf service exposed in public from my local. Also, the connecting progress bar is showing giving me idea that sharepoint designer can actually see the service.

[image]

Comment: SharePoint online needs to connect to your local WCF service. Have you exposed the service to be public? I mean can it be connected through the internet?

Comment: Hi @Amal,Thank you for responding. Yes, I already tried and put my service in public in Azure. I will update my question in a while with public url of my service.